# MetroApps not finding ResourceDictionary 2.0.0-alpha0748

Tags: mahapps.metro

I'm looking at utilizing the MetroApps 2.0.0-alpha0748 from Nuget. I've pulled that into my project and started implementing.

I am utilizing this inside of an existing application and this window will be called from an addin inside of that application. So I do not own the application context. So I have not utilized the typical Application.xaml Shared Resources, I was hoping to address that here.

Everything builds correctly. Whenever I run, I get the error below.

```
<Controls:MetroWindow x:Class="FamilyBrowser.Browser.ApplicationView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mah="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
        xmlns:helper="clr-namespace:RevitFamilyBrowser.BrowserHelper"
        xmlns:iconPacks="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/iconpacks"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FamilyBrowser.Browser"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:FamilyBrowser.BrowserViewModel"
        xmlns:view ="clr-namespace:FamilyBrowser.BrowserView"
        xmlns:Controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
        Title="Family Browser" Height="800" Width="800"
        MinHeight="300" MinWidth="400" Closing="Window_Closing"
    >
    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:ViewModelMain/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Themes/dark.red.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
         </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>
</Controls:MetroWindow>
```

[MahApps Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJTwu.png)

I downloaded the Code-Samples from MahApps.Metro and was able to build and run the HamburgerMenuNavigation example without any issues. I was also able to change the styles/themes example from dark.red to light.red to light.orange.xaml etc. without any issues to confirm that is was not a machine specific issue.

## **Update:**

```
<Controls:MetroWindow x:Class="FamilyBrowser.Browser.ApplicationView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mah="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
        xmlns:helper="clr-namespace:FamilyBrowser.BrowserHelper"
        xmlns:iconPacks="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/iconpacks"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FamilyBrowser.Browser"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:FamilyBrowser.BrowserViewModel"
        xmlns:view ="clr-namespace:FamilyBrowser.BrowserView"
        xmlns:Controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
        Title="Family Browser" Height="800" Width="800"
        MinHeight="300" MinWidth="400" Closing="Window_Closing"
    >
    <Controls:MetroWindow.DataContext>
        <vm:ViewModelMain/>
    </Controls:MetroWindow.DataContext>
    <Controls:MetroWindow.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Themes/Dark.Red.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Controls:MetroWindow.Resources>
    <Grid>
    </Grid>
</Controls:MetroWindow>
```

## **Update #2:**

We identified this was an error with another .dll loading in the 1.* library of MahApps even though I was loading the 2.* alpha content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Image to Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/neo90.png)

The original problem was because of other applications using MahApps while I was trying to use MahApps and loading both assemblies from different versions.

This could have been more quickly grasped by navigating to Debug > Windows > Modules to determine there were two different assemblies.

Answer (score 0):

the names are case sensitive. Please try `Dark.Red.xaml`. It should work with last alpha.

Happy coding
Tim

Comment: Swapped out to `<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Themes/Dark.Red.xaml" />` and produces the same exception.

Comment: I see there might be another issue. `Window.Resources` should be `Controls:MetroWindow.Resources` and for the `DataContext` as well.

Comment: I modified the remaining `Window` over to `Controls:MetroWindow`. Still throws the error for the Style. Should I raise an issue on GitHub and post a link to a repo to look at?

Comment: If you have the sample then you are welcome to post it here. I think It should work. If I still don't have a soultion, we can add an issue to github as well.

Comment: Updated the post above with the modified ApplicationView.xaml snippet.

Answer (score 0):

I took your snippet and put it into a new clean sample App. I just deleted the connection to the model as I don't have your model at hand.

Here is the result: 
[image]

and here is the modified XAML:

```xml
<Controls:MetroWindow x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
                      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                      xmlns:Controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
                      Title="Family Browser"
                      Width="800"
                      Height="800"
                      MinWidth="400"
                      MinHeight="300">
    <Controls:MetroWindow.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Themes/Dark.Red.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Controls:MetroWindow.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   FontSize="100"
                   Foreground="{DynamicResource MahApps.Brushes.Accent}"
                   Text="Hello World" />
    </Grid>
</Controls:MetroWindow>
```

I think there must be something else wrong in your App. If you can upload the not running sample on Github I may have a look if I find the bug. Maybe a `Style` or `StaticResource` is wrong or the MahApps-DLL is not found.

Happy coding
Tim

Comment: App.cs - https://gitlab.com/kraftwerk15/steel-yard/snippets/1964285
ApplicationView.cs - https://gitlab.com/kraftwerk15/steel-yard/snippets/1964286
ApplicationView.xaml - https://gitlab.com/kraftwerk15/steel-yard/snippets/1964287

Comment: I have no access to these pages. Are they marked as private?

Comment: App.cs - https://gist.github.com/kraftwerk15/a819cf9312183dc3c007a1f36f9b1db1
ApplicationView.cs - https://gist.github.com/kraftwerk15/0a39e79ca65306f3550177eb5da8842d
ApplicationView.xaml - https://gist.github.com/kraftwerk15/1c44bd49c70f3ec30e5662569c77ef7c

Comment: Sorry about that. Moved them over to be public on GitHub instead of GitLab.

Comment: I still think that there has to something wrong with how the dll is shipped on your side, but I never called a MetroWindow that way. You can try to add the `Resources` via code in your App.cs. Does it work with a normal WPF-Window?

Comment: It was working correctly with just being the window without any MahApps. I saw the samples posted for MahApps and MahApps had a much better hamburger menu and animations than I had, so I thought I would give it a try.

Comment: https://www.screencast.com/t/VheGe9fmgX

https://www.screencast.com/t/ZN4wFIWe6D

An image and a video showing what happens when loading as a WPF Window but trying to load the Resources.